# How to replace a string in a SQL Server Table Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-administration

I have a table (`SQL Sever`) which references paths (`UNC` or otherwise), but now the path is going to change.

In the path column, I have many records and I need to change just a portion of the path, but not the entire path. And I need to change the same string to the new one, in every record.

How can I do this with a simple `update`?

Answer (score 680, accepted):

It's this easy:

```
update my_table
set path = replace(path, 'oldstring', 'newstring')
```

Comment: I'd typically add `where path like '%oldstring%'` if there was a lot of data.

Comment: where condition make sense because if I have 50 rows in table and if I am replacing 10 rows with replace function it affects all 50 rows, even though it replaces 10 rows if you dont have where condition. But if you have where condition like mentioned in above comment it only affects 10 rows.

Answer (score 149):

```
UPDATE [table]
SET [column] = REPLACE([column], '/foo/', '/bar/')
```

Comment: sorry, not to be nitpicky after ten years but it's unclear from the answer if `foo` is being replaced or `bar`

(sorry again)

Answer (score 31):

I tried the above but it did not yield the correct result. The following one does:

```
update table
set path = replace(path, 'oldstring', 'newstring') where path = 'oldstring'
```

Comment: This totally defeats the purpose of using the replace method. You can accomplish the same thing like this:
    update table set path='newstring' where path='oldstring';

Comment: perhaps you meant `where path like '%oldstring%'`?

Answer (score 18):

```
UPDATE CustomReports_Ta
SET vchFilter = REPLACE(CAST(vchFilter AS nvarchar(max)), '\\Ingl-report\Templates', 'C:\Customer_Templates')
where CAST(vchFilter AS nvarchar(max)) LIKE '%\\Ingl-report\Templates%'
```

Without the `CAST` function I got an error

Argument data type `ntext` is invalid for argument 1 of `replace` function.

Answer (score 13):

You can use this query

```
update table_name set column_name = replace (column_name , 'oldstring' ,'newstring') where column_name like 'oldstring%'
```

Answer (score 11):

all answers are great but I just want to give you a good example

```
select replace('this value from table', 'table',  'table but updated')
```

this SQL statement will replace the existence of the word "table"
(second parameter) inside the given statement(first parameter) with the third parameter

the initial value is `this value from table` but after executing replace function it will be `this value from table but updated`

and here is a real example

```
UPDATE publication
SET doi = replace(doi, '10.7440/perifrasis', '10.25025/perifrasis')
WHERE doi like '10.7440/perifrasis%'
```

for example if we have this value

```
10.7440/perifrasis.2010.1.issue-1
```

it will become

```
10.25025/perifrasis.2010.1.issue-1
```

hope this gives you better visualization

Answer (score 8):

you need to replace path with the help of replace function.

```
update table_name set column_name = replace(column_name, 'oldstring', 'newstring')
```

here `column_name` refers to that column which you want to change.

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 6):

```
select replace(ImagePath, '~/', '../') as NewImagePath from tblMyTable
```

> where "ImagePath" is my column Name.
>  "NewImagePath" is temporery
>   column Name insted of "ImagePath"
>  "~/" is my current string.(old
>   string)
>  "../" is my requried string.(new string)
>   "tblMyTable" is my table in database.

Answer (score 4):

If target column type is other than varchar/nvarchar like **text**, we need to cast the column value as string and then convert it as:

```
update URL_TABLE
set Parameters = REPLACE ( cast(Parameters as varchar(max)), 'india', 'bharat')
where URL_ID='150721_013359670'
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can replace large text for email template at run time, here is an simple example for that.

```js
DECLARE @xml NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @xml = CAST((SELECT [column] AS 'td','',        
        ,[StartDate] AS 'td'
         FROM [table] 
         FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
select REPLACE((EmailTemplate), '[@xml]', @xml) as Newtemplate 
FROM [dbo].[template] where id = 1
```