# How do I replace the same thing in multiple columns within a SELECT statement in SQL?

Tags: sql, replace

I want to do a **SELECT** statement where I replace every (") with a (\") in **multiple columns**. Now how do I do that?

Is it possible to target more than one column with the REPLACE function within a SELECT statement?

I know this is **invalid** code but just to visualize what I mean:

```
SELECT REPLACE(firstColumn, anotherColumn, '"', '\"') 
FROM testTable
```

that of course **does not work** because the REPLACE function *expects only three parameters*.

I really need help with this as I couldn't find anything that worked for me yet.

thanks in advance!

**[edit - 24.04.2012 - 16:20 UTC+01:00]**

For those who might have a similar problem, this is my **solution**: I used *regular expression* to build my **SELECT REPLACE** statement which looks like this:

```
Regex: {(^[^, ]+,)}|( {[^, ]+,})|( {[^, ]+$})
```

In order to use this you need all your columns you want to go through each seperated with a comma and a space like this:

`ID, Gender, Firstname, Lastname, Street, Zip, City, EMail, Age,`

and then you need a tool (in my case Visual Studio) that is capable of replacing with tagged expressions (between the {} brackets in regex) and replace it with something like this:

`REPLACE(\1\2\3 'replaceMe', 'withMe') AS \1\2\3`

Hope this helps anyone who might have a similar problem. It is probably not the best solution but it worked for me. Thanks for the quick help!

Comment: I'd use an UPDATE statement which can target many columns. [Read more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169078/how-can-i-update-multiple-columns-with-a-replace-in-sql-server)

Comment: but then you'd need to use replace for each column separately in the UPDATE statement

Comment: SELECT REPLACE(firstColumn, '"', '\"'), REPLACE(secondColumn, '"', '\"') FROM testTable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your only sensible option is to use replace on every column individually.

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(firstColumn, '"', '\"'),
    REPLACE(secondColumn, '"', '\"')
FROM testTable
```

You could possibly do some clever pivoting of the data in order to only apply the REPLACE once but I don't see the benefit.

If the actual replace you are doing is very complex then you could write a function to do it to save code clutter and duplication.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like maybe it's more than you were looking to do, but something like the following should work:

```
declare 
  qrystart varchar2(15) := 'select replace(';
  qryend varchar2(31) := ', ''"'', ''\"'') from <your_table_name>';
  columnname varchar2(20);
begin 
  for columnItem in (
    select column_name from all_tab_columns
    where lower(table_name) = '<your_table_name>')
  loop
  columnname := columnitem.column_name;
    execute immediate qrystart || columnname || qryend;
  end loop;
end;
/
```