# Updating text in using SQL in a DAtabase

Tags: sql, text, replace

I am very new at SQL and keep getting erors when I try to change some text in my dataqbase for every instance.  I was told my syntax was incorrect:

I am tryingto change the text in the lst link to the second link.

UPDATE dbo.qanda

SELECT Replace(‘http://vhahacnonva.vha.med.va.gov/’, ‘http://nonvacare.hac.med.va.gov/’

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814548/how-to-replace-a-string-in-a-sql-server-table-column

Answer (score 2):

You are using a wrong `REPLACE` syntax. Also check your backtick, they should be quotes instead. Try this syntax

```
UPDATE dbo.qanda
SET columnname = REPLACE(columnname, 'http://vhahacnonva.vha.med.va.gov/', 'http://nonvacare.hac.med.va.gov/');
```

Just change `columnname` with your actual column name.

Comment: Right on the money, Fabio.