# How to fix emails containing double dot in domain?

Tags: mysql, email-validation

How do I update an email containing a double dot in its domain using raw mysql query?

So I have these emails having this format `sample_email@gmail..com` and turn it to this `sample_email@gmail.com`

Comment: @t.niese does that work in SQL?

Comment: @jpaugh sorry, somehow mixed two questions.

Comment: @t.niese NP. I *wish* you could do that in SQL! I think I found a SQL duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace a string in a SQL Server Table Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814548/how-to-replace-a-string-in-a-sql-server-table-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`replace`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) should do the trick:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    email = REPLACE(email, '..', '.')
WHERE  email LIKE '%..%'
```

Comment: You'll probably want to make sure there aren't legitimate occurrences of `..` in the database first. Something like `chris..something@gmail.com` may be technically valid.

Comment: @ceejayoz is there a way I can only target the double dot in the domain name?

Comment: @Lorence Well, first, I'd prevent this sort of invalid stuff from getting to the database. After that, you can clean things up by using MySQL's regex capabilities. (Or, do a `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE email LIKE '%..%'` - if there aren't any *legitimate* uses of `..` you can just run this update query).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use '%@%..%' as a like condition to extract all emails that have double dot on the domain.
Then split the text by @, replace in the domain and concatenate the text.

```
select email
    ,concat(left(email,instr(email,'@')),replace(right(email,instr(reverse(email),'@')-1),'..','.')) new_email
from
    (
    select 'sample_email@gmail..com ' email
    union
    select 'sample..email@..foo.com'
    union
    select 'other..sample..mail..@foo..com..org'
    ) t
where email like '%@%..%'
```