# How do I replace a char with another char in a database field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, replace

So this finds the bullet. I want to replace it with `'*'`

```
SELECT * FROM tblTrkRecordAction WHERE CHARINDEX(CHAR(0x0095), Comment) > 0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace a string in a SQL Server Table Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814548/how-to-replace-a-string-in-a-sql-server-table-column)

Comment: Please tag it next time.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to make this replacement in the comments field you could try this:

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(Comment, CHAR(0x0095), '*') AS new_comment
FROM tblTrkRecordAction
WHERE
    CHARINDEX(CHAR(0x0095), Comment) > 0;
```