# Replace specific strings in two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know most efficient and secure way to replace some numbers. In my table i have two columns: `Nummer and Vater`. In `Nummer` column i store articles numbers. The one with `.1` at the end is the '`main`' article and rest are his `combinations` (sometimes main article doesn't contain combinations). Numbers consist of 3-parts separated by **3 dots (always)**. Vater for all of them is always main article number as shown below:

```
Nummer        |   Vater
-------------------------------
003.10TT032.1   |  003.10TT032.1
003.10TT032.2L  |  003.10TT032.1
003.10TT032.UY  |  003.10TT032.1

Nummer column = varchar
Vater column = varchar
```

I want to have possibility to change first 2 parts n.n

For example i want to say and send via sql query that i want to replace to: `9.4R53`
Therefore based on our example the final results should be as follows:

```
Nummer    |   Vater
----------------------
9.4R53.1   |  9.4R53.1
9.4R53.2L  |  9.4R53.1
9.4R53.UY  |  9.4R53.1
```

Hope this is clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace a string in a SQL Server Table Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814548/how-to-replace-a-string-in-a-sql-server-table-column)

Comment: @PeterB Is this replace just enough for my purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try This

```
DECLARE @MysTR VARCHAR(50) = '003.10TT032.1'
DECLARE @RepStr VARCHAR(50) = '9.4R53'

SELECT
    MyStr = @MysTR,
    FinalStr = @RepStr+REVERSE(SUBSTRING(
                        REVERSE(@MysTR),
                        1,
                        CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(@MysTR))
                        ))
```

My Result

```
MyStr                                              FinalStr
003.10TT032.1                                      9.4R53.1
```

Comment: Hi, What about replace isn't enough as suggested above? I am not sure ...

Comment: To use replace you have to find the position of the second Dot. So This one is more easier to  reduce code complexity

Comment: Couldn't i just do like this? update table
set Nummer = replace(Nummer, '003.10TT032', '9.4R53') where path LIKE '%003.10TT032.'

Comment: But this won't work if the First 2 parts are different, in that case, you need to write separate replace for each. But My code will work perfectly for each without the need to individual Replace

Comment: But all two first parts are the same within one product if you look at my example.

Comment: But, you don't have to change it across multiple products, instead, you can just use the same code. I'm trying to make it more generic

Comment: why dont you use where? And where is update for vater, could you update your query please

Comment: You don't need the where since it a dynamic query. And this is a demo so you can do it in your table by yourself

Answer (score 1):

**Please try this**

```
DECLARE @Replace VARCHAR(50) = '9.4R53'
SELECT  CONCAT(@Replace,SUBSTRING(Nummer,CHARINDEX('.',Nummer,5),1000)) Nummer
       ,CONCAT(@Replace,SUBSTRING(Vater,CHARINDEX('.',Vater,5),1000)) Vater
FROM REplaces
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Nummer                         Vater
------------------------------ ---------------
9.4R53.1                       9.4R53.1
9.4R53.2L                      9.4R53.1
9.4R53.UY                      9.4R53.1

(3 rows affected)
```

Comment: Hi, What about replace isn't enough as suggested above? I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned your format is fixed, you can use [`PARSENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql) to achieve your expectation:

Sample data:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (Nummer VARCHAR (100), Vater VARCHAR (100))

INSERT INTO @TestTable (Nummer, Vater)
SELECT '003.10TT032.1',  '003.10TT032.1' UNION
SELECT '003.10TT032.2L', '003.10TT032.1' UNION
SELECT '003.10TT032.UY', '003.10TT032.1';

DECLARE @TextToBeReplaced AS VARCHAR (100) = '9.4R53.';

SELECT  @TextToBeReplaced + PARSENAME(Nummer, 1) AS Nummer, 
        @TextToBeReplaced + PARSENAME(Vater, 1) AS Vater
FROM @TestTable
```

Result:

```
Nummer      | Vater
-----------------------
9.4R53.1    | 9.4R53.1
9.4R53.2L   | 9.4R53.1
9.4R53.UY   | 9.4R53.1
```