# SQL Replace only a part of a path

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (about 160k rows) with a column called paths.
In that column there are paths like:

```
"\\ab.local\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder_x"

"\\ab.local\folderA\"
```

The length of the paths differ.

What I would like to do is to replace only the "ab" before the .local in to "cd" and leave the rest untouched.

I have been told to use a replace function, but somehow I don't get it to work the way I want to.

I am looking for the right syntax to do this.

Comment: Please show is your query which isn't working so we can help you correct it...

Comment: Also put different examples. Does it always start with \\? Is it always ab.? If not, is it always 2 chars and a dot? Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Declare @oldval as varchar(30) = '\\ab.local\' ;
Declare @newval as varchar(30) = '\\cd.local\' ; 

update yourtable set yourfield  = replace(yourfield,@oldval ,@newval) where yourfield like @oldval + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the part to replace is on a fixed position with a fixed length you could use `STUFF`, like so:

```
UPDATE yourTable SET paths = STUFF(paths, 3, 2, 'cd')
```

This replaces two characters in `paths` beginning at position 3 with `cd`

Answer (score 0):

Solved Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/814551/6923146

Hope it's perfect for your solution

```
UPDATE my_table
SET columnName = replace(columnName, 'oldstring', 'newstring')
WHERE columnName like '%oldstring%'
```

For example:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET columnName = replace(columnName, '\ab.', '\ab.')
WHERE columnName like '%\ab.%'
```