# SQL query to remove script tags from table column data

Tags: sql

I have a table `A` with a few columns; `Name` and `Description` store string data and are of type `nvarchar(250)` and `nvarchar(max)`.

Is there a way to clean up the faulty data in these columns to remove the script tags if any from them? This is the data as of now:

[image]

**Note:** code is being written in backend to strip tags for new entries being made to the table.

Comment: Check out `REPLACE()` function.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814548/how-to-replace-a-string-in-a-sql-server-table-column

Comment: I would need the same for all the values in a column, I need to do something like substring and concat and update the data with sanitized value. @RahulKPandey

Comment: see if this helps `DECLARE @y NVARCHAR(MAX) = '<script>My textMore text.</script>'

SELECT y.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM (
    SELECT y = CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(@y, '>', '/>'), '</', '<') AS XML)
) r`

Comment: Yes this works, but it is useful for a single column value, what do I do for an entire column values? @RahulKPandey

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:** 
Input:

```
col1    Name    Description
1   abstrat<script> testing<script>
2   abstrat100<script>  testing12<script>
3   abstrat101<script>  testing223<script>
4   abstrat102<script>  testing334<script>
5   abstrat103<script>  testing335<script>
6   abstrat104<script>  testing336<script>
NULL
```

```
UPDATE  dbo.StackExample
    set Name = coalesce((   SELECT top 1
                                CASE 
                                    WHEN Name LIKE '%<script>%' THEN SUBSTRING(Name, 0, charindex('<', Name, 0)) 
                                END AS Name1
                            FROM dbo.StackExample
                           ), Name)



UPDATE  dbo.StackExample
    set Description = coalesce((    SELECT top 1
                                CASE 
                                    WHEN Description LIKE '%<script>%' THEN SUBSTRING(Description, 0, charindex('<', Description, 0)) 
                                END AS Description1
                            FROM dbo.StackExample
                           ), Name)



SELECT  *
FROM dbo.StackExample
```

Output:

```
col1    Name    Description
1   abstrat testing
2   abstrat testing
3   abstrat testing
4   abstrat testing
5   abstrat testing
6   abstrat testing
NULL    abstrat testing
```