# SQL syntax to convert a value to transformed value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column value as -AE,IN,US,AU

I would like to fetch this value as -AE,-IN,-US,-AU

Please help in achieving this in SQL

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand whether the initial '-' is in the string or not, so I am given an answer with both string patterns.

Use **Replace** function. **REPLACE** doesn't use wildcards, it simply replaces all instances of the first string with the second string i.e. **Replace(ColumnNameOrFixedString, 'oldstring', 'newstring')**

I am given Sqlserver based syntax for creating table, but replace function work same in Oracle too

refer : [How to replace a string in a SQL Server Table Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814548/how-to-replace-a-string-in-a-sql-server-table-column)

```
Declare @table1 table (col1 varchar(500))

Insert into @table1 values ('-AE,IN,US,AU'), ('AE,IN,US,AU')

select Replace(col1,',',',-') ReplaceValue1, Replace('-'+col1,',',',-') ReplaceValue2 from @table1
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Well, this question is tagged with **Oracle** tag and code you posted wouldn't work there (most of it, that is). But, the **significant** part (`replace` function) would, so +1 from me.